# DDRescue Log File Corrupt after 6 week recovery

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, ddrescue

I've been runnning DDRescue on a 3Tb drive for almost 2 months and I had recovered about 2.8Tb when the system crashed and the log file I was using came out corrupt. I was able to recover portion of that log file but there is a gap in the sectors in the recovered log that makes DDRescue return an error when I launch it again. Here is a wetransfer link to see the log file: https://we.tl/58aSOeCOJo

I tried to edit the log file to take the corrupt data out but since this creates a 'gap' in the chronology of sectors, DDRescue doesn't seem to like that.

Thanks for any help, I really would like to avoid having to re-run DDRescue for another two months to save this drive...

Comment: What command are you using when you run ddrescue?

Comment: ddrescue -f -d -R -r3 /dev/sde /dev/sdf /mnt/somedir/logfiles/log3.log

Comment: Does anybody have an idea of how I could resume ddrescue from the last point it ended in the log file? Which seems to be at line 880828 where it says '0x2BA923A0000  0x00010000  *'

Comment: "I tried to edit the log file to take the corrupt data" -- how did you do that? Deleting binary garbage block is not enough because the lines that follow are only semi-valid, they repeat earlier lines. Did you delete them as well?

Comment: Yes I did try to delete the corrupt lines but that didn't work, DDrescue would say there is a problem in my log file on the exact line number I deleted from.

Answer (score 1):

To make this answer at least partially useful for other users with similar problems let's quote the crucial parts of your log here:

> ```
> # Rescue Logfile. Created by GNU ddrescue version 1.18.1
> # Command line: ddrescue -f -d -R -r3 /dev/sde /dev/sdf /mnt/somedir/logfiles/log3.log
> # Start time:   2017-08-14 10:22:44
> # Current time: 2017-08-14 12:13:09
> # Copying non-tried blocks... Pass 1 (backwards)
> # current_pos  current_status
> 0x27BF0520000     ?
> #      pos        size  status
> 0x00000000  0x02870000  +
> 0x02870000  0x001A0000  *
> 0x02A10000  0x00010200  +
> 0x02A20200  0x0005FE00  *
> # ...                          many lines here
> 0x2BA92360000  0x00040000  ?
> 0x2BA923A0000  0x00010000  *
> #                              binary garbage here
> 0xE4E1710000  0x00010000  *
> # ...                          many lines here
> 0x13D75970000  0x00000200  +
> 0x13D75970200  0x00
> ```

You identified the line just before the binary garbage to be the last valid one. It says `0x2BA923A0000  0x00010000  *` and it's the line number 880829 in your case. It makes sense because the lines after the garbage have lower positions (first numbers), they seem to duplicate earlier lines.

I did

```
<log3.txt head -n 880829 > log3new.txt
```

and run `ddrescue` (with `infile` being loop device from a large sparse file, it shouldn't matter though). It complained about the line 583658.

This is the line with its neighborhood:

> ```
> # ...
> 0x186C6940000  0x00000200  +
> 0x186C6940200 A9520200  0x0001FE00  *  # <- this line here
> 0x24AA9540000  0x00000200  +
> # ...
> ```

To fix this you should cover the whole range from `0x186C6940200` to `0x24AA9540000`, so the logfile is contiguous. The length is `0x24AA9540000`-`0x186C6940200`=`0xC3E2BFFE00`. The whole line 583658 should be:

```
0x186C6940200 0xC3E2BFFE00 ?
```

where `?` means non-tried blocks.

I made a fix with

```
sed -i '583658s/.*/0x186C6940200 0xC3E2BFFE00 ?/' log3new.txt
```

The resulting logfile is valid for `ddrescue`.

---

EDIT

> The problem I have though is that it's making DDrescue think that it's only recovered 2041GB while when the crash happened it was above 2800GB and as you can imagine these last 800GB took many weeks to be recovered.

In fact we don't know if it's the same 800 GB. There's a tool `ddrescueview`  (with GUI, available as `ddrescueview` package in Ubuntu) that will show you where exactly these non-tried blocks we introduced are. Note the current position is elsewhere:

[image: ddrescueview screenshot]

---

> So I'm wondering if the info after the garbage might have something to do with it? Any way we can include it in the log file?

I have isolated this "after the garbage" part, the last 129289 lines:

```
tail -n 129289 log3.txt > extra.txt
```

This command will show you lines that are in `extra.txt` but not in `log3new.txt`:

```
diff --suppress-common-lines extra.txt log3new.txt | grep -e '^<'
```

The output is

> ```
> < 0x13D75970200  0x00
> ```

It means only the last (incomplete) line from after the garbage isn't there before the garbage in the original `log3.txt`. Sorry, it seems to me `log3new.txt` is already the best you can get.

Comment: Thanks Kamil, that was very helpful! I was able to modify the log file and have it accepted by DDrescue. The problem I have though is that it's making DDrescue think that it's only recovered 2041GB while when the crash happened it was above 2800GB and as you can imagine these last 800GB took many weeks to be recovered. So I'm wondering if the info after the garbage might have something to do with it? Any way we can include it in the log file? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @ArnaudParis I have expanded my answer.

Comment: I see... I guess I'm gonna have to restart the process from 2.04Tb then and hope these 800Gb aren't the ones that took the longest to recover. Thanks again for all your explanation, this is making the whole process so much clearer to me. Now one other question I had about all this is that the disk I'm recovering is part of a RAID array and all the drives in this array are 3Tb. The drive I'm copying to is 4Tb, but if I wanted to transfer what I've copied so far to a 3Tb blank drive to match the original drive would it be possilbe to do so with DDrescue?

Comment: And is there an option in DDrescue that would allow me to 'compare' two drives sector by sector?

Comment: @ArnaudParis "if I wanted to transfer what I've copied so far to a 3Tb blank drive to match the original drive would it be possilbe to do so with DDrescue?" -- yes. If the disks are healthy then plain `dd` or even `cat` would do, `ddrescue` is the safe choice though. -- "And is there an option in DDrescue that would allow me to 'compare' two drives sector by sector?" -- I don't think so. If your aim is to compare this 4TB drive with the new 3TB one after you copy to the latter, use `cmp` with `-n` option. The number of bytes to compare will be the exact capacity of the smaller drive.